# Connectivity error in between Artifactory remote repo and NuGet gallery

Tags: ssl, devops, artifactory

I have Artifactory 7.x running on RHEL 7. Remote repository created to cache NuGet packages, Artifactory remote repo base is ‘https://www.nuget.org/’.

On day1, done below to configure SSL certs when curl to nuget.org failed and connectivity

```
          A] > cd /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors 
          B] > vi orgnuget.crt 
          C] > openssl s_client -showcerts -connect nuget.org:443 >> orgnuget.crt 
          D]  removed unnecessary data from orgnuget.crt and ensured that all 4 keys (0 to 3) with –BEGIN—and –END--
          E] copy orgnuget.crt to  /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/orgnuget.crt 
          F] > update-ca-trust extract 
          G] > curl -v https://nuget.org -> Successful 
          H] > cp orgnuget.crt /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/keys/trusted/ 
          I] > sudo chown artifactory:artifactory orgnuget.crt
          J] >  Restart Linux server 
          K] In Artifactory, test connection to https://nuget.org from remote repo, successful
```

On day2, curl to https://nuget.org successful , but In Artifactory, test connection to https://nuget.org from remote repo, failed with below mentioned error.

“Connection to remote repository failed: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target”

To fix the above error,  opened ‘https://www.nuget.org/’ in chrome, found ‘Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 05’ root issuer, downloaded the .crt and appended to orgnuget.crt and repeated all the above steps A to K , end up with same error in Artifactory connectivity test to remote repo to ‘https://www.nuget.org/’.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [KB Article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/)  "*How to resolve unable to find valid certification path to requested target” error"* and download the cert for nuget.org and import it into the trusted root certificate for Artifactory.  Once this is done, you will able to connect the Artifactory NuGet repository.